# Burning smell comes from the engine oil sump area

Tags: engine, maintenance, mazda, yamaha

My motorbike has been suffering from an issue which goes like this .
Whenever I drive for a few kilometres a smell comes from the engine oil sump area even if the engine oil is brand new .
One year ago when I replaced this engine oil with another then that particular issue dissappeared .
Now it makes me confused whether this problem was due to engine oil or other else

Answer (score 0):

Is the coolant circulating OK, and does the coolant temperature behave as it should? How about the oil - can you check that it's actually circulating round the engine? How's the oil pump? (I'm just throwing guesses out by the way - I'm not sure if motorbike engines even have similar cooling systems to what you'd find in a car).